# Web crawlers index links to group slides possible?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-3

How to get web crawlers to index links to slides in a group? Such as http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#gallery-1 with the data-caption "Corfe Castle Sunrise.."

Comment: Simply add "title" attribute?

Comment: I'm actually already using the title attribute and getting that as the caption.

Comment: In that case, I think there should not be any issue.